# WordPress article text issue

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I have changed the text area by editing the max-width from 696 to 1300

```
    .entry-content,
.entry-summary {
    margin-top: 34px;
    max-width: 1300px;
    width: 100%;
```

But that made two issues

1. The post footer on the left upper corner overlaps with it, so my text starts only after the post footer. I don't really understand what I have done, but I know that I want the text to start right next to the footer and after the footer it extended.
2. the text can exceed the page which enable the right/left scroll. How to make the text don't exceed the page?

[image]
I think that the problem is very clear using all mentioned above but feel free to visit the post that is in the screenshot
http://www.abdorefky.com/testing-homepage-margins/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the reason why it went down is because when you increased the width from 696px to 1300px, it's containing div (.entry-wrap) cannot contain it anymore since its only 1272px wide. So it has to bring down that div below the footer and even add a scroll bar. May I know what you intend to do?

Comment: well i just wanted my text to be at bigger area .
i didn't know that max was 1272 .

Comment: i want my text to start next to the footer. and after the footer it expand

Comment: Oh ok. Well, if you want, you can apply this css. This will take advantage of the 100px padding on the left by lowering, and at the same time increase the width of the div.

Comment: .entry-content {
    padding-left: 50px;
    max-width: 900px;
}

Comment: You can play around with the padding-left and max-width to suit your needs :)

Comment: i removed the padding + max-width 1000. but

Comment: when you look the page you will find that the space down the footer is not used

Comment: Try applying this

Comment: entry-content {
    float: none;
}

Comment: oki, btw i have corrected the code at the header . looks like contect and summary and wordking together

Comment: added float: none; but nothing happened

Comment: Sorry, I think you may have missed the  dot in front of "entry-content". Try this below instead

Comment: .entry-content {
    float: none!important;
}

Comment: oki this one worked . 
now how to make padding for  that part

Comment: can i make padding for the floating part only ?

Comment: For entry content, you can use padding-left, padding-top, padding-right, or padding-bottom, all using px

Comment: You can also use margin-left, margin-top, etc

Comment: but that will make padding to the whole text . 
even the one that is not floating

Comment: i think i made it :)

Comment: padding-left:100px !important;

Answer (score 1):

The content div shares a CSS class with `.entry-content`, which appears to be overriding `.entry-summary`

Try updating your .entry-content CSS.

There is a `padding-left: 100px;` under `.entry-content`, which is indenting your content.

Comment: with out the padding it will start from 100 px to the left .

Comment: you did understood something i don't,  which is entry-content and entry-summary

Comment: what is the different. ( i am totally new, but fast learner ) so please give me the big overview