# wordpress blockquote not working on mobile

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

welcome.
i am using blockquote on my website, and it's working fine with computers.
but when it come to mobiles, there is a huge issue

[image]

here is my blockquote setting :

---

```
blockquote p {
font-family: "Playfair Display", serif;
color:#000000;
margin-right:250px;
margin-left:150px;
padding:25px;
font-size: 14px;
line-height: 1.3421052631;
margin-bottom: 51px;
background:#e9eff3;
border-left-color:#87a6bc;
border-left-style:solid;
border-left-width:2px;
border-right-color:#87a6bc;
border-right-style:solid;
border-right-width:2px;
border-bottom-color:#87a6bc;
border-bottom-style:solid;
border-bottom-width:2px;
border-top-color:#87a6bc;
border-top-style:solid;
border-top-width:2px;
}
```

i think that the problem is very clear from the above description. 
but feel free to test by your self wwww.abdorefky.com

Comment: thanks Siva. can i make the photo at smaller size ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For what I seen the problem is in the mediaquery:

```
blockquote p {
    font-size: 1em; /* I recommend you to put 1em instead of 34px */
    font-weight: 400;
    line-height: 1;
    margin-bottom: 34px;
    margin-left: 0;  /* add this */
    margin-right: 0; /* add this */
}
```

if you add the `margin-left`and `margin-right` to the mediaquery it should work

Comment: thanks for help. but i before i make the edit i noticed that you say that mediaquery .

Comment: is that mean i will add the code you mean under the media query ?

Comment: view-source:http://www.abdorefky.com/wp-content/themes/ryu/style.css?ver=79cb8d18df19bc02dae891bde067063a
@media screen and (max-width: 600px)
It's near the end

Comment: half fixed, i think the problem now is that the text don't start from the far left

Comment: Maybe you mean the padding? if it's that you have it a 25px try change it.
`padding: 5px` or `padding: 25px 5px`

Comment: not the padding. it's the margin 
looks like there is a global settings that push the whole blockquote to the right

Comment: actually looks like it's the whole text :(

Comment: here is what is see -- https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B_En0WCYnzMsMUFBVjJaUmJvTFE

Comment: maybe the padding . i don't know

Comment: Ah! That's for : `.entry-content, .entry-summary {padding-left:150px !important;}` i think that is not really important but you can put `padding-left: 0` in the mediaquery; entry-content it's the only problem here; if you can search for lines it's in the 891

Comment: here is the reason for the padding in entry-content or summary 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39183380/wordpress-article-text-issue

Comment: but in the mediaquery if you put `padding-left: 0` it doesn't work? you have to erase the !important in the `padding-left: 150px` or else takes priority to that padding

Comment: i wont drag you in other issues .

Comment: i will create another question to troubleshoot this issue

Comment: Sorry for not being helpful with the other problem :/